# How to execute inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation? | PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a specific code (for example)

```
def beginmain():
    print('hello world')
beginmain()
```

Everything works correctly, but I want to execute the TabError (inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation). How do I make it?

Comment: At some points in your code you use spaces and at some points you use tabs to indent. This is not allowed in python. Replace all your tabs to spaces, to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you saying you want to raise a `TabError` intentionally?

Comment: Yes, that is my reasonable goal

Answer (score 0):

Which IDE do you use?

For example, in the settings of PyCharm, you can arrange if it accepts 4 spaces as tab or not. If you choose not and use 4 spaces it gives that error message.